# llvm, load poolalloc to opt

Tags: c++, llvm

I want to run alias analysis in llvm, particularly I want to run [-ds-aa](http://llvm.org/docs/AliasAnalysis.html#the-print-alias-sets-pass) which is in module `poolalloc`. According to `poolalloc` documentation I need to load it's module to `opt`.
What I do is :

```
 opt -load /usr/local/lib/LLVMDataStructure.so -load /usr/local/lib/poolalloc.so -ds-aa -aa-eval hello.bc -disable-output -stats
```

But I get next output:

```
opt: Unknown command line argument '-ds-aa'.  Try: 'opt -help'
opt: Did you mean '-no-aa'?
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. How to run `-ds-aa` alias analysis in llvm?

Comment: Could [this](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmdev/2012-April/048841.html) be relevant?

Comment: yes, it is relevant, if you post it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that ds-aa was discontinued due to lack of use and other issues; see:

http://llvm.1065342.n5.nabble.com/DSA-or-rDSA-td6954.html
and
http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmdev/2012-April/048841.html